# Firemonkey Delphi XE7 app does not work in Lollipop

Tags: delphi, android-5.0-lollipop, firemonkey, delphi-xe7, android-anr-dialog

I need your help with a problem with my Android app developed in Delphi XE7 Upd1 Firemonkey. I'm trying to find a solution to the problem below of this lines from two days ago that it drives me crazy and I'm giving up.

Situation: My app is working fine on devices with Android KitKat 4.x, it was developed in Delphi XE7 Upd1, recently, in the enterprise that I work, changed all the devices to new ones with Lollipop 5.0.

Problem: When I installed the app to the new devices, it doesn't work anymore, ANRs, unexpected closes, freezes, sometimes it does not start...
I've tried with many tests but none of them worked.

1. I installed the hotfix for FireMonkey apps on Android 5.0 (http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30110), my app uses some bitmaps, and problem continues.
2. I deleted all bitmaps in the app and problem continues.
3. All packages in SDK Manager are up to date and problem continues.
4. By testing, I installed the MultiView and TabSliding basic project samples of Rad Studio 15.0 on the new devices, and oohhh, ANR still continues.
5. Finally, I installed the TabSliding basic project sample of Rad Studio 17.0 (Delphi DX 10) and works fine, but if open a TabSliding basic sample project of Rad Studio 15.0 in Delphi DX 10 and deploy to the new device, ohhhhhh nooooooo, ANR appears.

Did anybody experience this problem? Is there any solution for the Delphi XE7 Firemonkey app to work fine on Lollipop?

Comment: Hi! Has my last comment helped you?

Comment: Hello Sergey, many thanks for your help and interest, the hotfix didn’t solve the issue, so I finally decided to test it in a trial Delphi XE8 (which compatible with my thirdparty components) and runs fine, from now work for my bosses to decide migrate to XE8.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

First, about samples. They need to be recreated sometimes, if you open them earlier versions of Studio. Now, about the problems you've met. Can it be https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-11575 ? What is a concrete model of your device?

Comment: The devices are Terra Pad 1003 (tablets) with Lollipop 5.0 imported from Germany for work in production with orders, items stocks…
The bug fix that you mentioned is for Delphi DX 10, but as I said in the above lines to the help of the other user, my app uses some third app components and incompatibles with Delphi DX 10, I only tested samples projects of Delphi XE7 in Delphi DX 10 to see if it works in Lollipop. I need that my app deploy in Delphi XE7 works in Lollipop, thanks for your appreciate help.

Comment: The issue I've mentioned is about the hotfix itself. It occurred to be unsafe on some devices, so later it was removed in DX10. Copy FMX.Graphics.Android.pas to your project and try to change GetTmpFileName function so, that it returns some other path. E.g. Result := TPath.GetDocumentsPath. Rebuild and run.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using Delphi 10 for Lolipop but I do recall that at some point I had to delete Delphi's project files, create a new project and manually add all forms and units of my project in order to work. Try also to delete the AndroidManifest.xml file found in your project's dir. It will be automatically recreated. As always keep a backup of your initial code.

Comment: I'm sorry, but my app uses some third app components and incompatibles with Delphi DX 10, I only tested samples projects of Delphi XE7 in Delphi DX 10 to see if it works in Lollipop. I need that my app deployed in Delphi XE7 works in Lollipop, thanks for your appreciated help.